# Convert a Composite Pattern to a new one with additional behavior

Tags: c#, design-patterns, decorator, composite

I am running a little problem with our design.

We have an internal framework in which we are using the composite pattern to represent a hierarchical data structure :
[image: Framework domaim model object]

This hierarchical data structure is returned by a "Read file" method from the framework to our application and is also used by other application.

Now in our application, we need exactly the same data structure (a composite pattern) but with additional behavior: we need an extra GetCompareText() method for each entity. And this method should be definable in each entity:

[image: Application Domain Mode object]

- **ContainerEntity** should implement the default behavior for the GetCompareText method for "Containers"
- **LeafEntity** should implements the default behavior for the GetCompareText method for "Leaves"
- Some leaf entities can ovveride the behavior (For example, LeafEntityA must override the behavior, but LeafEntityB must have the default behavior)
- Some Container entities can override the default behavior (ContainerEntityA uses default behavior, when ContainerEntityB overrides it).

How can we achieve this ? 
Do we need another Composite Pattern in our Application? Is Decorator pattern an option ?

I hope I was clear enougth

Thanks for your assistance!

Benoît

Comment: Do you need to separate the GetCompareText behaviour between the framework and the application? You could include the GetCompareText in the IEntity-implementing objects (returned from the framework) and then just consume them via their interfaces in the application.

Comment: It's an option, but I would prefer to separate this. The GetCompareText is something really related to the our new application. And I think, other applications which are using the framework shouldn't know this behavior.

Comment: Decorator seems the obvious choice in that case? You could also look at the Visitor pattern and only allow your specific application to access entities for GetCompareText behaviour but that's adding more hierarchical complexity to your design??

Comment: Ok I will have a look at the Visitor pattern too. For the Decorator pattern, I'm not sure yet how I should implement it. And then how to "convert" my framework object to an application object.

Comment: Is your compare behaviour generic or does each entity have different implementations for it? If it's generic (or not changing much), you could use extension methods to implement your decoration application-side (I'm assuming you're using C#).

Comment: Yes, we are using C#. Our domain model object contains something like 50 different entities. And right now, maybe 10 or 15 entities will need their own implementation of GetCompareText. Other entities should use the default GetCompareText.

Answer (score 0):

I have implemented the Decorator pattern for my Domain Model Object like this:

[image: Decorator Pattern]

Is this implementation correct?

What would be the best solution to retrieve the appropriate "Decorator" for any Entity (return an instance of the Decorator if it exists, otherwise, return the Default Decorator)?